# Is there a way to annotate django query with non-expression?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I have use case where I need to get all objects where `existing_field` is the beginning of `some string`.

`some string` changes dynamically so I need a smart way to filter out objects.

My idea is to create annotated query like this:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(annotated_field='some string').filter(annotated_field__startswith=F('existing_field'))
```

Currently it is failing with:
`QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): some string`

Is there a way to annotate objects with string value?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking but try [Value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) expression.

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(annotated_field=Value('some string', output_field=CharField())).filter(annotated_field__startswith=F('existing_field'))
```

Comment: Great thanks. Solved it in the meantime like you said but first annotated then filtered. `annotated_field` needs to be created first.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still facing the problem with newer versions of Django will have to use `ExpressionWrapper` and probably `F`

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F
MyModel.objects.annotate(annotated_field=ExpressionWrapper(Value('some string', output_field=CharField()))).filter(annotated_field__startswith=F('existing_field'))
```